# Create a new iOS backup without deleting the previous one

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, backup

When I go into iTunes and do a manual `back up now` it deletes the previous backup (as seen in `Preferences > Devices > Backups`.  Is there a way to create a new backup without deleting/over-writing the old one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close: `Preferences > Devices`

then Ctrl-click the backup name. Select `Archive` from the pop-up menu. The backup will be renamed something like "Device - Feb 2, 2015 20:03". The next backup will be a new one named "Device".

Yay [Mystery Meat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystery_meat_navigation).

Comment: King among men.